# Using dynamic column and table names in Join in MariaDB/MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm not sure how to do this or if it's even possible but conceptually it would look something like this:

```
SELECT item_id, CONCAT('field_data_', `field_name`) AS t2,     CONCAT(`field_name`, '_value') AS f
FROM (
   BIG SELECT STATEMENT
) AS t1
JOIN {t2} ON t2.{f} = t1.item_id
```

Where {t2} in the JOIN is coming from the created field via concatenation and {f} in the JOIN is coming from the other field created via concatenation.

That is {t2} and {f} are substituted with the values of the fields instead being taken as literally t2 & f. I thought it might be done with something like COLUMN_GET but I'm not sure how to make that work in the JOIN part.

Is this possible?

Comment: T2 is a field, so it cannot be used as a table in the from clause. You can use expressions in the join condition, but you cannot use field aliases defined in the select list because the select list is interpreted after the from clause. Honestly, I do not get the question, since there is only 1 table (a derived one) in the from clause, so no idea what the join should do there.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. Table names, column names, and all other elements of the SQL query must be fixed at the time the query is parsed. You can't make a query do different things based on what it discovers about data during execution.

This would be like asking, "Can I write a Java function that returns a value, but the value it returns determines which function I call?"

Comment: I figured as much but it was worth asking anyway. Thanks.